# Regex pattern to split based on first and last words

Tags: python, regex, nlp

```
address='''No-33-6,BEML Layout,Basaveshwaranagara 8th Main,Kamala Nagar,Near Academy Of Science and Knowledge,Bengaluru,Karnataka 560079'''
```

I tried using below pattern.But .* matches all characters

```
re.findall('[n][o].*',adress)
```

Match based on first term that is No and last term 6 digits pincode/zipcode

```
output:No-33-6,BEML Layout,Basaveshwaranagara 8th Main,Kamala Nagar,Near Academy Of Science and Knowledge,Bengaluru,Karnataka 560079
```

Comment: I tried this  re.findall('[N][o].*',address) but it doesnt seem to match the last numbers

Comment: Updated the question with the sollution i tried

Comment: if first word starts with No and last word ends with number(6 digit) then whole starting from first word till last digits will be output

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your query correctly you wish to match a string pattern that begins with

> No

And ends with the last term 6 digits pincode/zipcode

> i.e. 560079

And all the text in between.

You can achieve this as follows:

```
import re
address='''No-33-6,BEML Layout,Basaveshwaranagara 8th Main,Kamala Nagar,Near Academy Of Science and Knowledge,Bengaluru,Karnataka 560079'''
matches = []
matches = re.findall(r'\b(?=No)(.*)\b(\d{6,})\b', address)
```

This returns:

> [('No-33-6,BEML Layout,Basaveshwaranagara 8th Main,Kamala Nagar,Near Academy Of Science and Knowledge,Bengaluru,Karnataka ','560079')]

see here: https://regex101.com/r/2pXcMI/4

Comment: It works.Thanks for the link mentioned.It is very helpful for me.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. If you're happy I would appreciate it if you could accept the answer :)

Comment: Dont forget to accept an answer if youre satisfied :) Of course give it time but i imagine there are many ways you could achieve this using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
([N][o]).*\b([0-9].....).*?$
```

Does this work for you? Should match first word based on your regular expression that you tried and then capture the last 6 digits in the address. You can test it here https://regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall('/No.+\d+/g', string_to_search)
```

From start to finish:

Firstly we want to match the prefix "No" so we simply use the two letters without brackets or square brackets.

Next we must ensure that at the number is suffixed. In most cases the length of this number won't change, however my answer incorporates a method for any length integer.

If both of those are there then the match is true.

Therefore we want to collect all info inside. This is done with `.+` which means "one or more character except for the newline character"